# Looking for SLAs pertaining to endpoint responsiveness

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Could you please point me at documents you might have detailing your expected responsiveness of HERE geocoding APIs please? I'm after something more concrete than 99.9% availability.

Also, if I'm waiting for 40 minutes or 14 hours for a batch job containing a single address to be processed, does that fail 99.9%?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the SLA-report by logging into developer.here.com and going to https://developer.here.com/sla-report. Batch jobs are POST requests and the time to complete your request depends on the queue size (there would be other requests waiting) and the batch size. So this doesn't fail 99.9%.

Comment: So what are considered to be acceptable wait times for a submitted batch job (in 'accepted' state after submit call) to be processed? 'depends' is not really adequate for my needs, does HERE provide any guarantees /  upper bounds on the waits for jobs to be processed or is it considered acceptable to have 12+ hour waits?

Comment: Usually the wait isn't too long(assuming not most users are querying the batch api at that point). If you are a paid user please contact the sales team to clarify the wait time.

Answer (score 0):

For a single address as you listed will take just few milliseconds. Anything above that, especially 40 min indicates that you are probably not connected. This includes invalid address input as the result will be back telling you that the address is not found. You can check the previous status using RequestID from the request  like that https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs/
E2bc948zBsMCG4QclFKCq3tddWYCsE9g
?action=status
&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}

In general, if your address has more address tokens, it will take longer to return comparing to if it has fewer address tokens.
example 
USA vs 1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500,USA